# Porting from TFS to Git

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, git, tortoisegit

I am popular with TFS for a long time but now I am required to port to Git.
After some days, I have some problems I need your helps:

- TFS defines WorkItem and checkins will be put in this WorkItem. I easily get all changed files in WorkItem to create a deployment packages. WorkItem is awesome in TFS because when I have 2 tasks which run in same time, I create 2 WorkItem for each task, I easily check-in files in WorkItem I want. Now on Git, I don't find this feature.
- How to archive only changed files in **selected** commits (1 or more commits). I am using TortoiseGit like a GUI and Git Source Control Visual Studio Extension. Please help me on them. I don't like to use command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Git is a version control system, TFS is version control as well as many other things like task management, build servers, etc.

To get the functionality you are after (if I understand you correctly) you would need to integrate git with visual studio.

Luckily microsoft is working on something that may help.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx

Additionally check out the [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Checkintool) commands. It appears some of them allow you to resolve work items

Comment: Seems that the integration is available for vs 2012, OP seems to be using vs 2010. Good resource though.

Comment: I still use the Visual Studio 2010. No money for upgrading :(

Comment: Do you need any of the features that are in the paid versions? Git support will work with the Visual studio 2012 express version